# Openstack setup error (failed to create symbolic link '/var/run/ovn/openvswitch': File exists)

Tags: vmware, openstack

im working on a school project building an Openstack Cloud Computing and im following a guide video.

The installation was smooth and then this error pops up:

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/run/ovn/openvswitch': File exists

/devstack/tools/worlddump.py:22: DeprecationWarning:
 The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12.
 Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives
```

can u guys help me out ? thanks alot, btw im new in this one.

Answer (score 0):

this error accord because you reinstall the script you need to delete

```
/var/run/ovn/openvswitch
```

by execute the command

```
sudo rm /var/run/ovn/openvswitch
```

and then run

```
./stack.sh
```